# Loading commonvoice with torchaudio not working

Tags: python, pytorch, torchaudio

If I try to load commonvoice with torchaudio it returns difeferent size tensors.

when i try loading commonvoice using

```
train_dataset = COMMONVOICE(root='/home/mr/Downloads/cv-corpus-7.0-2021-07-21/de/', tsv='train.tsv')

# Create data loader
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True, num_workers=0)
```

and then use it in a for loop like this

```
for inputs, targets in train_loader:
```

I get the error `RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [150822] at entry 0 and [127008] at entry 1`

```
import torch
from torchaudio.datasets import COMMONVOICE
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
train_dataset = COMMONVOICE(root='/home/mr/Downloads/cv-corpus-7.0-2021-07-21/de/', tsv='train.tsv')
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True, num_workers=0)
print(device)
for inputs, targets in train_loader:
    print(inputs, targets)
```

Even this simple code produces the same exact error

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please help if you know the answer.

Comment: the error is clear: `stack expects each tensor to be equal size`. However, it is difficult to help beyond this without the code...

Comment: What do you mean by "without the code" the for loop is the code that raises the error when feeding it objects from the data loader created in the code before.